# How to extract x and y values as a new array after running DBSCAN?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, dbscan

I am running DBSCAN algorithm in python by using list of points created in ArcGIS. I applied a loop to see differences for increasing eps and min_feature values. It works very well and I can plot the results on a graph. But I have to use the resulting points in clusters on ArcGIS Pro again. To be able to do that I would like to extract x and y values of each point in the clusters -which I can see it on the graph- and to a .csv or .xlsx file. Then I can visualize all the points and the clusters on the map that I am currently working. The problem is I cannot print the x and y values and to be honest I am a novice and not sure where to find them. Since I do not use a basemap and only working with the vector data I could not find any other way to do it. I would be grateful if someone can help with the issue. Thank you in advance. Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import arcpy
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter as xlsw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

in_workspace = r'D:\00_Experiment\DWG_Participants\Database'
arcpy.env.workspace = in_workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# #############################################################################
# Generate sample data

input = r"D:\00_Experiment\DWG_Participants\Database\DbScan.gdb\FP_Centroids"
arr = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(input, ("Longitude", "Latitude"))

cen_df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]
cen_df, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=len(cen_df), centers=centers, cluster_std=0.4,
```

random_state=0)

```
cen_df = StandardScaler().fit_transform(cen_df)

# #############################################################################
# Compute DBSCAN
a = 0.2
b = 0.5

for i in range(1):
    a = a + 0.1
    b = b + 0.5
    db = DBSCAN(eps=a, min_samples=b).fit(cen_df)
    core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
    core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
    labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
    n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
    n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

    print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
    print('Estimated number of noise points: %d' % n_noise_)
    print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels))
    print("Completeness: %0.3f" % metrics.completeness_score(labels_true, labels))
    print("V-measure: %0.3f" % metrics.v_measure_score(labels_true, labels))
    print("Adjusted Rand Index: %0.3f" % metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels))
    print("Adjusted Mutual Information: %0.3f" % metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels))
    print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f" % metrics.silhouette_score(cen_df, labels))

# Black removed and is used for noise instead.
    unique_labels = set(labels)
    colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
    for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
    for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
        if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
            col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

        class_member_mask = (labels == k)

        xy = cen_df[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
        plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col), markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

        xy = cen_df[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
        plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col), markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

    ###################
    #I tried this code for xy values and labels but the excel file does not contain what I am looking for 
    #new_array = np.array(labels)
    #df = pd.DataFrame(labels)
    #df = df.transpose()
    #xlsfile = r"D:\00_Experiment\DWG_Participants\Database\output_dbscan.gdb\fp.xlsx"
    #writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsfile, engine="xlsxwriter")
    #df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="table_fp",startrow=1, startcol=1, header=False, index=False)
    #writer.save()
    #######################

    plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
    plt.show()enter code here
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure if I understand you correctly. You have created a plot of x and y values and you would like to know the x,y values that you have plotted? That would mean that the values you are looking for are in the variable `xy`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @tomsal. When I extract variable xy it is completely empty but I still can see the values on the graph. I have no idea what is missing there.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want to store a table of the x,y,labels? One side note: I do not know whether it is due to the formatting, but could it be that the code you ran did not have the right indentation? At the position where I see it in your post it would only act on the last set of `xy`.

Comment: Thank you @tomsal. I rewrite the script in a complete different way. The issue was using make_blobs and dbscan together in a wrong way. For my case make_blobs was not needed and I removed that part completely. it worked perfectly.